# Cannot GET / request

Tags: javascript, node.js, phusion

My router does not seem to work on remote server but it works perfects on local server.
I've tried with so many methods to solve it but yet no results.

At first, the error that gave me had something to do with phusion, hence if the if statement in app.js and now it gives no error in log, but on browser it shows: cannot get /

Please help me solve, code snippets below:

> app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app') 

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) != 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}
const port = process.env.PORT || 9100;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

> index.js

```js
if (process.env.ENV !== "development") {
  require('dotenv').config();
}
// console.log(process.env)
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');

// Routes imports
const admin_users = require('./routes/admin/users');
const admin_locations = require('./routes/admin/locations');
// const admin_products = require('./routes/admin/products');
const admin_deliveries = require('./routes/admin/deliveries');
const admin_payments = require('./routes/admin/payments');
const admin_dashboard = require('./routes/admin/dashboard');
const admin_orders = require('./routes/admin/orders');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const products = require('./routes/products');
const deliveries = require('./routes/deliveries');
const payments = require('./routes/payments');
const tickets = require('./routes/tickets');
// const files = require('./routes/files');
const cards = require('./routes/cards');


let app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(helmet());
// app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));
// view engine setup


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Access-User, X-Access-Token,Authorization");
  // next();
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    //respond with 200
    return res.status(200).json({});
    // next();
  }
  else {
  //move on
    next();
  }
});

// Routes
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
  res.send('server is up and running');
})
app.use('/admin/users', admin_users);
app.use('/admin/locations', admin_locations);
// app.use('/admin/products', admin_products);
app.use('/admin/deliveries', admin_deliveries);
app.use('/admin/payments', admin_payments);
app.use('/admin/orders', admin_orders);
app.use('/dashboard', admin_dashboard);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/products', products);
app.use('/deliveries', deliveries);
app.use('/payments', payments);
app.use('/tickets', tickets);
// app.use('/files', files);
app.use('/cards', cards);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


require("./scheduler")

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  let err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

require('./server');

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `router.get('/users'` and then `app.use(router)`, instead of `app.use('/users'`?

Comment: Thanks, I've noted this, but it doesn't still work

Comment: `My router does not seem to work on remote server but it works perfects on local server.` What doesn't work exactly? Errors in the Node console surely?

Comment: How can i solve it?

Comment: I actually have a log file of errors. But when it comes to "Cannot Get /". No error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this code below

```
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
  res.send('server is up and running');
})
```

and replace it with

```
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
  res.send('server is up and running');
})
```

Place it below

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')